# React-native-vector-icons ios error

Tags: ios, react-native

I get the following error:

> RNVectorIconsManager not available, did you add library to your
>   project and link with libRnVectorIcons.a

after npm installing the [React-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) and running react-native link. I am using react-native v0.42, react-native-vector-icons v4.0.0 and Xcode v8.2.1.
I have checked plist and it has all the fonts in array. and libRNVectorIcons.a is showing under build phases but it is red. see image:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try running `react-native link react-native-vector-icons` in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The broken file:
[https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/local-cli/core/**fixtures**/files/package.json](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/local-cli/core/__fixtures__/files/package.json)

Try running `react-native link`

or simply remove the above broken file and restart your xcode.